# Find the area bounded by the region representing all possible positions of point P(x,y) if P satisfies the equation [|x|]+[|y|]=1.

Tags: calculus

Find the area bounded by the region representing all possible positions of point P if P satisfies the equation [|x|]+[|y|]=1.

Comment: The set of solutions of that equation is not a curve. This let me to think that there are two meaningful questions that may be asked: 1. The area enclosed in the hole enclosed by the set of solutions. 2 Or the area of the set of solutions itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

If $[\cdot]$ is the floor function (as I suppose) this is the graph of the curve.  Can you find the area?

[image]

---

For $x,y >0$ the possibilities are:

$\lfloor x \rfloor=0 $ and $\lfloor y\rfloor=1$ that is $0\le x < 1$ and $1\le y <2 $

or

$\lfloor x \rfloor=1 $ and $\lfloor y\rfloor=0$ that is $1\le x < 2$ and $0\le y <1 $

Comment: Then it is easy, but how to draw the graph mathematically?

Comment: Hint:$$0+1=1\\1+0=1$$no more is possible

Comment: $[|1.5|]+[|0.5|]=1+0=1$ but $(1.5,0.5)$ is not in your curve. The set of solutions is not a curve.

Comment: I added to my  answer. You can extend to the other values by symmetry.

Comment: Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Even without a graph:

By symmetry, the area you are looking for, is $4$ times the area of $\{(x,y)\colon x,y\ge 0 \land [x]+[y]\le 1\}$.

Now we can describe the good poins (on the positive part of the plane, there will be 3 cases only).

To have $[x]+[y]\le 1$ for positives, we have to have $[x]=[y]=0$ or $[x]=0,\ [y]=1$ or $[x]=1,\ [y]=0$.

The first case means $x\in[0,1)$ and $y\in[0,1)$, so $(x,y)\in[0,1)\times[0,1)$, the area of this set is $1\cdot 1=1$. Second and third case is analogical, you have area $1$ also.

Hence the answer is $$4\cdot(1+1+1)=12$$

---

The solution uses the fact that area of line segment is $0$.